# gitignore doesn't ignore files in repository

Tags: git

I have defined the following `.gitignore`:

```
/aclocal.m4
/config.guess
/config.sub
```

However after reconfiguration and rebuild, `git status` still reports:

```
# On branch master
# Changed but not updated:
#   (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#       modified:   aclocal.m4
#       modified:   config.guess
#       modified:   config.sub
...
```

I'm expecting it to say something like:

```
#       deleted:    aclocal.m4
...
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You were tracking those files before?

Comment: files already in git have precedence over the .gitignore definition.  gitignore will only prevent new files from entering the git realm, not remove existing files from it.  This leaves you in control, you would not want the repository to be automagically wipped clean because of a bug in gitignore file now would you ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It sounds like those files are already being tracked by git. In that case you will first have to remove them from git (e.g. `git rm filename`). Then they will be ignored.

Answer (score 4):

You are referring to files at root of the filesystem not in your repository.

You need something like

```
aclocal.m4
config.guess
config.sub
```

If they have previously added them to the repository, you will also need to remove them (eg `git rm aclocal.m4`).